# how to copy by value variable instead of by refrence python

Tags: python, function, arguments, pass-by-reference, argument-passing

I have the following function:

```
def myfunc(str):
    x = str # i need to copy str into x , not but ref
```

I tesed `copy Module` but it didn't work.

**My question** is, How i `copy` instead of `by ref` str into x?

Comment: When you say that `copy` "didn't work" what do you mean?

Comment: x = str[:]
x = copy.copy(str);  but i get the `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: Don't name your variables `str`, that might be part of your problem.

Comment: i renamed, but i goot same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since strings are immutable, there's no real difference between "by value" and "by reference" in your specific case.